# Very large wx.ScrolledPanel rendering

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to display a **very large** map in a scrollable window.  The idea is that you have a grid of square tiles with an image for each tile and you can scroll around to see them.  Each tile also has some numerical information (I could draw this with a wx.StaticText), and you can click and right click on the tiles to perform certain actions.

My first pass at this has been to use wx.Panel for each tile and wx.ScrolledWindow for the map.  However, the wx.ScrolledWindow seems to have very poor performance with large numbers of tiles (scrolls at about 4fps).

My next attempt was to use a [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) by having exactly 9 large panels that render about a hundred tiles each using wx.dc.  As the user scrolls in one direction and panels move off the screen, I add them to a deadpool and reconfigure new panels from the deadpool.  However, this does not seem to perform particularly well either, because there is a signficant flicker whenever a panel is repositioned.  Also, it seems that panels inside a wx.ScrolledWindow  are positioned (e.g. `panel.SetPosition(...)`) according to the current scroll position rather than the origin of the virtual space, and this makes it difficult to avoid race conditions as the scroll position could change while the panels are still being reconfigured.

What is the recommended pattern to render very large scrolling content in wxPython?  I'm familiar with a way to achieve this in my native WM, and I have seen [fairly large scroll areas](http://www.audio-evolution.com/AE4/AEImages/ScreenShot2.gif) implemented in wxWidgets.  But there do not seem to be any examples out there for large scrolling content for wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the better way to scroll large content is with [wx.lib.floatcanvas](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.floatcanvas-module.html).  There's a reasonable demo [on GitHub](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/FloatCanvas.py).  It's not quite native speed, but it's usable even on large graph sizes.

I haven't figured out how to do the 2D multitouch panning that the native scroller (on Mac) supports, as it doesn't seem to show up in the MouseWheel events.  That could be a drawback if it's important to somebody's usecase, but it's not the end of the world for my project.